# Why p:first-child doesn't apply for first paragraph if there is a <script> in the top of <body> in HTML-file?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

`p:first-child` doesn't apply for first paragraph if there is a `<script>` in the top of `<body>` in HTML-file.

If you move `<script>` to the bottom of `<body>` - it works.
And it doesn't matter where CSS-style is (it's among tags or it's a file)).
For example

```
 p:first-child {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
```

it doesn't apply for first(or any) paragraph until I moved script to the bottom

Comment: `:first-child` selects the first child element among a group of siblings. That's all. By adding `p` in front of it, you effectively add a filter to `first-child` that says only apply my rules if the first child happens to also be a paragraph. What it doesn't do is target the first paragraph in your page

Comment: Would be nice if you could include HTML code too.

Comment: Not sure why j08691 posted as a comment instead of as an answer.

Comment: @TariqulIslam I don't see why that would make a difference

Comment: @robartsd Didn't feel like much of an answer. Felt like like a rtfm type thing. Plus there are dozens or more of this type of question on SO

Comment: I understood the issue! Thanks j08691!

Comment: @j08691 Not significant for this post, but as a general suggestion for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:first-child` will select any element that is the first child of its parent element. `p` will select any paragraph element. `p:first-child` will select any paragraph element that is the first child of its parent element. If your paragraph is a direct descendant of the body element, having any other elements in the body before the paragraph will cause it to not be the first child of the body element. You could add a div around all your paragraphs and leave the script at the beginning of the body; the first child of the div would then be styled by `p:first-child` if it is a paragraph element.

Comment: Well explained.

Comment: Very informative! Thanks!